cannot install ubuntu studio 24.04 from live session - desktop installer never finishes loading
I have managed to boot into Ubuntu-Studio 24.04 live from pxe ,
so now I am running around in the live session desktop environment.
I can also see the "install" icon on the desktop , which -in previous versions- would normally allow me to start the installation of ubuntu-studio to some local hard disk.
unfortunately the new installer does fully load: I see the window titled "welcome to Ubuntu Studio" popping up and internally the windows contents show a circling whisker and "Preparing Ubuntu Studio" but it does not go anywhere from there.
I think a picture is self-explanatory here:

do you have any idea how to see some progress here ?
Alternatively can I start the installer from the terminal ?
thank you for your help!
note: this thread is titled similarly but it did not help.
note2: during pxe boot no grub pops up to allow me to select to install directly to the local hard disk
note3: the /dev/sda is already visible in the OS and the partition table has been set using cfdisk (partition table type : gpt)

Does sudo journalctl -f show some subiquity-server dying messages? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1519337/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap-launcher-always-crashes-on-xubuntu-24-04

As of this writing, Ubuntu Studio has never been tested against, and therefore does not support, PXE boot.
Source: I'm the Ubuntu Studio lead.

after discussing with U.St. lead it appears the multi-layered squashfs approach used by the ubuntu-bootstrap-subiquity server (which came to replace ubuntu-installer) is somehow affected by the pxeboot (probably because of the kernel option "ignore_uuid" which was necessary to get the image to boot into live session anyway.

Just to be more precise, that would be ubuntu-desktop-provision which provides ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap and acts as a graphical frontend to a subiquity server in the localhost. We could speculate until eternity why it doesn't work properly. subiquity itself is used as the installer for Ubuntu Server and, as I understand it, is PXE bootable, but also might not be a layered image, so we've entered pure speculation territory.
