ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap launcher always crashes on Xubuntu 24.04
I've been trying to install Xubuntu 24.04 on my new Lenovo v15 G4 with integrated AMD Radeon graphics card and SSD hard drive, for a couple of days without success. There is no dual boot, only the SSD hard drive previously partitioned by me with Gparted.
I boot a Bootable USB with Xubuntu 24.04 in UEFI mode and when I start the installer (ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap) it always stops working. Sometimes it doesn't start, other times it goes two steps and then stops working, etc.
I don't know if it's important, but when I start the live USB the following error appears: "error file /boot/ not found". However, it starts without a problem.
I have tried the following things without success:

Boot with and without secure boot mode (although I have read that it is advisable to leave it activated to install with UEFI)

I have disabled Fast boot (so it can recognize the USB when booting)

Start the live USB in safe graphics mode

I have used several pen drives

I have used all USB ports

I have created the live USB with several applications: Startup Disk Creator, dd, Balena Etcher,... (not Rufus because I don't have Windows)

I have checked the integrity of the ISO image

I have used a daily ISO image

Do not change the language during installation

Do not connect to Wi-Fi during installation

Update the ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap snap package previously

Start the installer from the terminal with the following command:
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap_ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap.desktop LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 /snap/bin/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap


And nothing has helped me... If I run the application from the terminal it returns the following warnings when closing:

Add the last log:
2024-07-02 13:49:14.591597 DEBUG config: Loaded config file from /usr/share/desktop-provision/whitelabel.yaml
2024-07-02 13:49:14.592136 INFO flavor_provider: Using flavor from config: UbuntuFlavor.xubuntu
2024-07-02 13:49:14.592241 INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds
2024-07-02 13:49:14.592737 ERROR subiquity_server: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = /run/subiquity/socket, port = 0
2024-07-02 13:49:15.597176 INFO subiquity_server: ApplicationState.CLOUD_INIT_WAIT
2024-07-02 13:49:16.599505 INFO subiquity_server: ApplicationState.CLOUD_INIT_WAIT
2024-07-02 13:49:17.601904 INFO subiquity_server: ApplicationState.CLOUD_INIT_WAIT
2024-07-02 13:49:18.659549 INFO subiquity_server: ApplicationState.WAITING
2024-07-02 13:49:18.659973 INFO subiquity_client: Opening socket to Endpoint(/run/subiquity/socket )
2024-07-02 13:49:18.660711 DEBUG desktop: Disabling automounting
2024-07-02 13:49:18.661371 DEBUG subiquity_client: POST http://localhost/meta/client_variant?variant=%22desktop%22
2024-07-02 13:49:18.672001 DEBUG telemetry: Writing report to /var/log/installer/telemetry
2024-07-02 13:49:18.707519 ERROR desktop: Failed to set show-volumes to DBusBoolean(false)
    GSettingsSchemaNotInstalledException: GSettings schema org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding not installed
2024-07-02 13:49:19.409571 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> setVariant(Variant.DESKTOP) null
2024-07-02 13:49:19.410811 ERROR desktop: Failed to set show-network-volumes to DBusBoolean(false)
    GSettingsSchemaNotInstalledException: GSettings schema org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding not installed
2024-07-02 13:49:19.410879 DEBUG desktop: Disabling screen blanking
2024-07-02 13:49:19.411804 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.WAITING, confirmingTty: , error: null, nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.42541, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.42541, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.42541)
2024-07-02 13:49:19.412069 DEBUG subiquity_client: POST http://localhost/meta/mark_configured?endpoint_names=%5B%22mirror%22%2C%22proxy%22%2C%22ssh%22%2C%22snaplist%22%2C%22ubuntu_pro%22%5D
2024-07-02 13:49:19.415790 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> markConfigured([mirror, proxy, ssh, snaplist, ubuntu_pro]) null
2024-07-02 13:49:19.421291 DEBUG desktop: Disabling screensaver
2024-07-02 13:49:19.433791 DEBUG desktop: Inhibiting Gnome session
2024-07-02 13:49:19.441 ERROR desktop: Failed to inhibit Gnome Session
    DBusServiceUnknownException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
2024-07-02 13:49:19.453041 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.WAITING, confirmingTty: , error: null, nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.42541, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.42541, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.42541)
2024-07-02 13:49:19.454396 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.WAITING, confirmingTty: , error: null, nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.42541, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.42541, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.42541)
2024-07-02 13:49:19.454620 DEBUG subiquity_client: GET http://localhost/meta/interactive_sections
2024-07-02 13:49:19.456716 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> getInteractiveSections() null
2024-07-02 13:49:19.457387 INFO locale: Loaded 75 languages
2024-07-02 13:49:19.457480 DEBUG subiquity_client: GET http://localhost/locale
2024-07-02 13:49:19.461810 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> locale() "en_US.UTF-8"
2024-07-02 13:49:19.461981 INFO locale: Selected en_US as UI language
2024-07-02 13:49:19.480944 ERROR sound_service: Error playing sound with id: system-ready (most likely missing canberra-gtk-play)
2024-07-02 13:49:21.671477 INFO locale: Selected es_ES as UI language
2024-07-02 13:49:22.688287 INFO locale: Set es_ES as system locale
2024-07-02 13:49:22.688390 DEBUG subiquity_client: POST http://localhost/locale
2024-07-02 13:49:25.204002 ERROR ubuntu_bootstrap: Unhandled exception
    HttpException: HttpException: Connection reset by peer, uri = http://localhost/locale

2024-07-02 13:49:25.204203 INFO subiquity_status: WAITING => null

Edit: I can install Xubuntu 22.04.4 without problems.
Thank you very much

Look at this question https://askubuntu.com/q/1513407/1698042

Thank you Talaat, but It's too complicated for my knowledge

In the end, I was able to solve it by deactivating both the WIFI connection and the LAN connection. Although the installer stopped working at some step, trying it again completed the installation successfully.
Once the system has started, I have updated it and installed the package:
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras


Thank you, I was having ubuntu_bootstrap using 100% cpu while the installer just gave the "spinning icon on the button" for the "optimise your computer" step...forever...  to fix disable wifi (not just have it not connected to a network) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision/+bug/2064052
